# Question about the assignment operator in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Forgive what might seem to some to be a very simple question, but I have this use case in mind:

```
struct fraction {
    fraction( size_t num, size_t denom ) : 
        numerator( num ), denominator( denom )
    {};
    size_t numerator;
    size_t denominator;
};
```

What I would like to do is use statements like:

```
fraction f(3,5);
...
double v = f;
```

to have `v` now hold the value represented by my fraction. 
How would I do this in C++?

Comment: Why are you using size_t? Why not use unsigned int or long? Also, what if someone wants a negative fraction? You might want to add a boolean sign unless you're willing to make either the numerator or the denominator (or both) signed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this is to define a conversion operator:

```
struct fraction
{
  size_t numerator;
  size_t denominator;

  operator float() const
  {
     return ((float)numerator)/denominator;
  }
};
```

Most people will prefer not to define an implicit conversion operator as a matter of style. This is because conversion operators tend to act "behind the scenes" and it can be difficult to tell which conversions are being used.

```
struct fraction
{
  size_t numerator;
  size_t denominator;

  float as_float() const
  {
     return ((float)numerator)/denominator;
  }
};
```

In this version, you would call the `as_float` method to get the same result.

Comment: that integral division always catches me

Comment: It's another of those C/C++ gotchas.  +1 for as_float though.  This is the same reason there's c_str() on std::string.  It's just too easy to get yourself into trouble with implicit conversions.  Although for a numeric case like this, it may well be just fine.

Comment: Thank you. I used the double version of your operator float() const.

Comment: I believe you can use "explicit operator float() const" to make the cast only work when explicit, and not be available for behind-the-scenes shenanigans.  Then you'd have to say "double myDouble = static_cast<float>( myFraction );" or equivalent.  (Actually, just googled this, it looks like it's only standard in C++0x.  Most of the compilers I've worked with have supported it for a while.)

Answer (score 3):

Assignment operators and conversion constructors are for initializing objects of *your* class from objects of other classes. You instead need a way to initialize an object of some other type with an object of your class. That's what a conversion operator is for:

```
struct fraction {
     //other members here...
     operator double() const { return (double)numerator / denominator;}
     //other members here...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the operator double to convert:

```
struct fraction
{
     operator double() const
      {
         //remember to check for  denominator to 0
          return (double)numerator/denominator;
      }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`operator=` has nothing to do with it, rather you want to add to your `struct` a public `operator double` something like:

```
operator double() {
  return ((double) numerator))/denominator;
}
```

Comment: edited to fix syntax (thought I already had but clearly hadn't, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

With that much of code it will be compiler error as the compiler doesn't how to convert struct fraction into a double. If you want to provide the conversion then you have to define the `operator double()` which will be used by the compiler for this conversion.